# Shortcut for YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration does not work

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I installed YouCompleteMe (https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#general-usage) for Vim with Vundle. In my .vimrc I have:

```
   nnoremap <leader>g  :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
```

But when I type `Ctrl-g` at the befining of a variable in a file opened with Vim, nothing happens. `YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration` works though. 
When I type `:let mapleader` in vim I get the error `E121: Undefined variable: mapleader`

How can I make the short command `Ctrl-g` an 'alias' for `YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration` ?

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl` is not by default the leader and is best not chosen as a leader because it has so many other shortcuts associated with it. To map `Ctrl-g` though you just need to define it like this:

```
   nnoremap <C-g>  :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
```

For more information on the leader key check out this article: https://tuckerchapman.com/2018/06/16/how-to-use-the-vim-leader-key/